# Having an error when installing Scann on Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, retrieve-and-rank, protobuf-python, scann

I installed `scann` on `colab` with code `!pip uninstall protobuf>=3.20.3` but I had a error like that:

```
"ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-datasets 4.9.2 requires protobuf>=3.20, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-metadata 1.13.1 requires protobuf<5,>=3.20.3, but you have protobuf 3.19.6 which is incompatible."
```

I also installed `!pip uninstall protobuf>=3.20.`3 first but still get the same error.
I want to run a recommendation model having link "https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval"

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue that `pip dependency error` message shows up when there are mismatch protobuf version defined for different required modules.

This error will not interrupt the code execution in Google Colab.
For other platforms(Jpuyter, Pycharm, VScode), installing **protobuf 3.20** using `pip install protobuf==3.20` explicitly after all the required module install, will fix the issue.